# Extraction of name type required id parameters from xml stored in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, excel, xml, t-sql

I need help in extraction of name, type, required, id, parameters from XML column stored in SQL table. Can someone please guide me on what link or book I can refer to get this information. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Please find below XML for reference:

```
<FORM>
  <PAGES>
    <PAGE Title="Record Input Sheet">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD Name="ddlStatus" type="DropdownList" Caption="Status" required="true" id="Status">
          <PROPERTIES>
            <PROPERTY name="ID">ddlStatus</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY name="BackColor">lightyellow</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY name="Width">75</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY name="onchange">CategoryPopulate(' ')</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY name="CssClass">form-control</PROPERTY>
          </PROPERTIES>
          <LISTITEMS>
            <LISTITEM value="">Select</LISTITEM>
            <LISTITEM value="Adjudicate">Adjudicate</LISTITEM>
            <LISTITEM value="Skip">Skip</LISTITEM>
            <LISTITEM value="Cancel">Cancel</LISTITEM>
          </LISTITEMS>
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </PAGE>
  </PAGES>
</FORM>
```

I have written the below code to extract the properties and listitem but unable to extract the parameters of the column:

```
select 
    [XmlFile].value('(/FORM/PAGES/PAGE/FIELDS/FIELD/PROPERTIES/PROPERTY)[1]','varchar(255)') ,
    [XmlFile].value('(/FORM/PAGES/PAGE/FIELDS/FIELD/PROPERTIES/PROPERTY)[2]','varchar(255)') ,
    [XmlFile].value('(/FORM/PAGES/PAGE/FIELDS/FIELD/PROPERTIES/PROPERTY)[3]','varchar(255)'),
    [XmlFile].value('(/FORM/PAGES/PAGE/FIELDS/FIELD/LISTITEMS/LISTITEM)[1]','varchar(255)') 
from 
    tbl_reference 
where  
    [QueueName] = 'ReferenceQueue';
```

Comment: What's the required output?

Answer (score 1):

SQL-Server has a quite enhanced support to deal with XML. What you are looking for are the native XML methods of the XML data type `.value()`, `.nodes()` and `.query()`. [Find details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017).

Try it out:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<FORM>
  <PAGES>
    <PAGE Title="Record Input Sheet">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD Name="ddlStatus" type="DropdownList" Caption="Status" required="true" id="Status">
          <PROPERTIES>
            <PROPERTY name="ID">ddlStatus</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY name="BackColor">lightyellow</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY name="Width">75</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY name="onchange">CategoryPopulate('' '')</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY name="CssClass">form-control</PROPERTY>
          </PROPERTIES>
          <LISTITEMS>
            <LISTITEM value="">Select</LISTITEM>
            <LISTITEM value="Adjudicate">Adjudicate</LISTITEM>
            <LISTITEM value="Skip">Skip</LISTITEM>
            <LISTITEM value="Cancel">Cancel</LISTITEM>
          </LISTITEMS>
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </PAGE>
  </PAGES>
</FORM>';

SELECT pg.value('@Title','nvarchar(max)') AS PAGE_Title
      ,fld.value('@Name','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_Name
      ,fld.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_type
      ,fld.value('@Caption','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_Caption
      ,fld.value('@required','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_required
      ,fld.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_id
      ,fld.query('PROPERTIES/PROPERTY') AS FIELD_Properties
      ,fld.query('LISTITEMS/LISTITEM') AS FIELD_ListItems
FROM @xml.nodes('/FORM/PAGES/PAGE') A(pg)
OUTER APPLY A.pg.nodes('FIELDS/FIELD') B(fld);
```

The idea behind:

Calling `.nodes()` on `/FORM/PAGES/PAGE` will return a derived table with all pages (if there are more than one). Then we use another call to `.nodes()` to get a derived table of all fields below each page.

The `.value()`-method is used to get the internal values. In your case these are attributes, hence the `@`.

I do not know, how you want to deal with the internal properties and list items, so I included them just *as is*.

### UPDATE

According to your comment, the following query is a little enhanced: The properties are picked by their names, while the list of *list items* is returned as a comma separated string.

```
SELECT pg.value('@Title','nvarchar(max)') AS PAGE_Title
      ,fld.value('@Name','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_Name
      ,fld.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_type
      ,fld.value('@Caption','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_Caption
      ,fld.value('@required','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_required
      ,fld.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS FIELD_id
      ,fld.value('(PROPERTIES/PROPERTY[@name="ID"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Prop_ID
      ,fld.value('(PROPERTIES/PROPERTY[@name="BackColor"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Prop_BackColor
      --more properties--
      ,STUFF(
       fld.query('for $li in LISTITEMS/LISTITEM
                  return <x>{concat(",",$li/text()[1])}</x>
                 ').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS ListItems_separatedByBlanks
FROM @xml.nodes('/FORM/PAGES/PAGE') A(pg)
OUTER APPLY A.pg.nodes('FIELDS/FIELD') B(fld);
```

About the properties:
The part `[@name="ID"]` is called *predicate*. It is a `XQuery` filter and can be read as *take the Property, where the attribute `name` is `ID` and pick its `text()`*.

About the list items:
This is a little hack [using a FLWOR-XQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery?view=sql-server-2017). It can be read as *Run through the list items and return a new XML, where each `text()` is prefixed with a comma*. Using `.` as `Xpath` in `.value()` will return *all of them in one*. The `STUFF()` function is needed just to cut away the leading comma.

Comment: Wow! This is really very helpful, thanks a ton @Shnugo. Really appreciate it.          
The attributes are perfect that is how I wanted to place them. Apologies for not being precise with the internal properties and list items requirement. Currently the FIELD_Properties and  FIELD_ListItems is displaying the properties and listitems in  xml format. I was looking to see if I could have the properties in one cell (comma separated) and list items in another cell for respective fields.